# Fast way for calculating difference between each element of numpy array given certain condition

Tags: python, numpy

Given a numpy array, I am trying to find the difference for each element pair with the condition that the difference should be less than 1000000 and greater than -1000000

```
pairWiseDiff = np.array([])
for ts in timestamps:
    diffTime = timestamps - ts
    individualTimeDiff = diffTime[np.logical_and(diffTime<1000000.0, diffTime>-1000000.0)]
    pairWiseDiff = np.append(pairWiseDiff, individualTimeDiff)
```

This script works well for the use case where the length of input array is less than 40000. However, I want to get the results for an array of length 150000 where the above script turns out to be extremely slow.

Suggestions for improving speed?

Comment: instead of a for loop, you could use np.where( (diffTime<1000000.0 & (diffTime>-1000000.0) )

Comment: @Prakash047 How should the OP do that? The loop, as it stands, is handling different `timestamps` giving different `diffTime`.

Comment: What is the size of `timestamps`? Maybe you can vectorize instead of running it as a `for` loop?

Comment: And is timestamps a 1d or 2d array?

Comment: 1. How big an array is `timestamps`?  You could make a 2D array, but might run into memory problems if it is big 2. Aren't you getting errors from `np.append` for dimension mismatches?  There's nothing assuring `individualTimeDiff` is always the same length.

Comment: Sorry, need I to read better on question 1.

Comment: @JohanL `timestamps` is 1d array of 150000 elements.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `timestamps` is 1d. Abusing `(a-b) = -(b-a)` and `np.absolute`.

```
def filterDiff(ts, d, f = lambda x: np.absolute(x)):
    i, j = np.triu_indices(ts.size, 1)
    diffs = ts[i] - ts[j]
    mask = f(diffs) < d  
    out = np.zeros((ts.size, ts.size))
    out[i[mask], j[mask]] = diffs[mask]
    out[j[mask], i[mask]] = -diffs[mask]
    return out
```

**EDIT:**  For n-d arrays

```
def filterDiff(ts, d, f = lambda x: np.absolute(x)): # f must return scalar from ts.shape[1:]
    i, j = np.triu_indices(ts.shape[0], 1)
    diffs = ts[i] - ts[j]
    mask = f(diffs) < d  
    out = np.zeros((ts.shape[0], ts.shape[0],) + ts.shape[1:])
    out[i[mask], j[mask]] = diffs[mask]
    out[j[mask], i[mask]] = -diffs[mask]
    return out
```

**EDIT 2:**  For memory problems, you may need to chunk up your `diffs` and `mask` computations.  You can play around with `mem` to fit as much in memory at once as you can.

```
def filterDiff(ts, d, mem = 200000000, f = lambda x: np.absolute(x)):
    i, j = np.triu_indices(ts.shape[0], 1)
    t = i.size // mem + 1
    i, j = np.array_split(i, t), np.array_split(j, t) 
    diffs = []   # iterating and constructing over lists is easier than arrays
    for k, (i_, j_) in enumerate(zip(i, j)):
        diff_ = ts[i_] - ts[j_]
        mask = f(diff_) < d
        diffs.append(list(diff_[mask]))
        i[k], j[k] = i_[mask], j[mask]
    diffs = np.array(diffs)
    i, j = np.hstack(i), np.hstack(j)
    return i, j, diffs
```

Depending on how sparse `mask` is, how you want to handle exceptions, or what follow-on calculations you're doing, you may want to skip generating `out` (as I did for the memory-saving version) and `return i[mask], j[mask], diffs[mask]`.  You can also make `out` a [`scipy.sparse.coo_matrix`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.1/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.coo_matrix) or [`np.ma.maskedarray`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.html) object instead.

This should reduce the number of calculations from `O(n^2)` to `O(n*(n-1)/2)` and get rid of your many `for` loops.

Comment: I am sure you solution is quicker, but `O(n*(n-1)/2)` is  `O(n^2)`. The constant does not matter in big-Oh notation.

Comment: @DanielF there is no function called `triu.indices` that I could find. Is is `triu_indices`?

Comment: Yes.  Sorry, hand-copied code from an airgapped workstation.

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the number of computation of pairWiseDiff to less than the half. timestamps has `N` elements, pairWiseDiff has `N*N` elements. Consider pairWiseDiff: the first line are zeros, and the other elements are symmectric to the diagonal, which you don't have to compute twice. So from the `N*N` elements you have to compute only `(N*N - N)/2`.

In my solution pairWiseDiff has still `N*N` elements. You might improve that with numpy tri-diagonal arrays. And probably the for loop can be eliminated with numpy.roll and/or numpy.slice.

```
import numpy as np
timestamps = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])+10
N = len(timestamps)
pairWiseDiff = np.zeros((N,N))

for n in range(1,N):
    pairWiseDiff[n,n:N] = timestamps[n:N] - timestamps[0:N-n]
    print(n,timestamps[n:N])

pairWiseDiff
```

Comment: this script will give `memory error` because we are generating `pairWiseDiff` for N=150000 as mentioned in my question

Comment: Check carefully: if `N = len(timestamps)` then pairWiseDiff already has `(N*N) = reshape(N,N)`  elements in your code. I'will give you a comparision in an additional/seperate answer below.

Answer (score 0):

With 1000 elements in timestamp only you can get already a **speed up of factor 1000** when you avoid unnecessary calcucaltions and when you avoid `np.append(pairWiseDiff, diffTime)`. `runA` is your code, `runB` avoids `np.append` and `runC` avoids unnecessary calculations.

```
run A:      1 loop,  best of 3: 1.64 s per loop
run B:    100 loops, best of 3: 7.5 ms per loop
run C:    100 loops, best of 3: 6.8 ms per loop
```

The question is, wether you realy need the `N*N = reshape(N,N)`- array `pairWiseDiff`, because all the information you need and you get out of `timestamps` is given by:

```
Dif  =  timestamps -timestamps[0]
```

Here the 3 codes I compared:

```
timestamps  = np.arange(1000) + 10

def runA(timestamps):
    N = len(timestamps)
    pairWiseDiff = np.array([])
    for ts in timestamps:
        diffTime = timestamps - ts
        #individualTimeDiff = diffTime[np.logical_and(diffTime<1000000.0, diffTime>-1000000.0)]
        pairWiseDiff = np.append(pairWiseDiff, diffTime)
    return pairWiseDiff.reshape(N,N)

def runB(timestamps):
    N = len(timestamps)
    pairWiseDiff = np.zeros((N*N))
    for n,ts in enumerate(timestamps):
        diffTime = timestamps - ts
        #individualTimeDiff = diffTime[np.logical_and(diffTime<1000000.0, diffTime>-1000000.0)]
        j = slice( N*n,  N*(n+1) )
        pairWiseDiff[j] = diffTime
    return pairWiseDiff.reshape(N,N)

def runC(timestamps):
    N = len(timestamps)
    pairWiseDiff = np.zeros((N,N))
    Dif  =  timestamps -timestamps[0] 
    #iDif = diffTime[np.logical_and(Dif<1000000.0, Dif>-1000000.0)]
    for n in range(0,N):
        pairWiseDiff[n,n:N] =   Dif[0:N-n]
        pairWiseDiff[n,0:n] =  -Dif[n:0:-1]
    return pairWiseDiff

%timeit runA(timestamps); #print(pairWiseDiff); print()
%timeit runB(timestamps); #print(pairWiseDiff); print()
%timeit runC(timestamps); #print(pairWiseDiff); print()
```

Comment: yes, 150'000 is a lot. On my computer `run_A`  ended never... -  have you ever been successful to run it ? What operations do you do with `pairWiseDiff` afterwards ? No memory problems then ? Perhaps `numpy.memmap` can be a solution ?